# Ubuntu: how do I install specific java update with apt-get?

Tags: ubuntu, apt, software-installation, java

I would like to install a specific update of JVM on my Ubuntu. Is that possible to do with `apt-get`? I am looking for version `1.8.0_151` and as of now if I run `apt-get install -y oracle-java8-installer` I get version `1.8.0_161`, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're installing `oracle-java8-installer` from the PPA `webupd8team/java`, there is only one version currently available:

```
$ apt-cache policy oracle-java8-installer
oracle-java8-installer
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 8u161-1~webupd8~0
  Version table:
    8u161-1~webupd8~0 500
      500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
      500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
```

If, in the future, you find a package that you'd like to install a specific version of, and there are multiple versions available to download, the specified version can be installed using an `=` after the package name. For example:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2=2.2.20-1ubuntu1
```

For now, I'd recommend downloading the `1.8.0_151` package [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-javase8-2177648.html).

Comment: You say "in the future", does it mean that `apt-get` doesn't support it yet? 
So, my only option would be using `wget`  if I want to perform installation completely in the console?

Comment: My apologies, what I meant to get across is that if you require specific-version packages in the future (that have multiple versions), you can install the specified version using the syntax above.


`wget` would normally be the go-to option; however, Oracle requires a registered account to download older versions of Java software. You also are required to accept the code license before downloading. Perhaps try a command-line browser such as `lynx`, `w3m`, or `elinks`?

Comment: this should do it, I guess 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10268583/downloading-java-jdk-on-linux-via-wget-is-shown-license-page-instead

Comment: And you can see which versions your various `sources.list` entries support by using the `madison` option for `apt-cache` - ie, `apt-cache madison oracle-java8-installer` or `apt-cache madison chromium-browser`